# Can you exclude a tag from showing up?

Tags: support

Is there a way to look at all questions that have come up except for ones you don't want to see (i.e. futurama)? Basically can you block yourself from seeing certain tags?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes!

You can add the tag to your list of ignored tags.

Go to your profile, click "Edit Profile & Settings", and make sure you're on the Preferences tab:

[image]

From there you can also hide all questions with ignored tags by selecting the "hide questions in your ignored tags" option.

Comment: Oh wow...somehow I didn't notice that. Thanks

Comment: disappointed... it doesn't really hide the questions, just grey's them out... I don't want to even see them at all...

Comment: @JonathanMiller You should use the checkbox I mentioned then.

Comment: Omg, I can see non-futurama questions again! Hazaa!

Comment: sorry, I am apparently blind and/or stupid...

Comment: I don't think this is how it works anymore. I don't see this in my settings. Has this process changed? This is pretty important as this question is linked to [avoiding star wars spoilers](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7708/how-to-avoid-star-wars-spoilers?cb=1).

Comment: @thomas Oh yeah, thanks. I updated the instructions to match the current profile design.

Comment: Excellent, this is tremendously useful. I don't often get the opportunity to interact with any SE devs. So I'll take this opportunity to say: Thanks for all the work you do. I love this community. Cheers.

Comment: @thomas Thanks, glad to hear you're enjoying things around here. :)

Comment: Any way we can get the mobile apps to honor the hide/grey out preference? I've got mine set to hide, and I still see questions with ignored tags on iOS. Another user said they have the same issue on android.

Comment: @phantom42 I don't know much about how the mobile apps work. If this doesn't already exist, it's best to post a separate request.

Answer (score 3):

For a one-shot, you can also search for `views:0 -[futurama]`

Answer (score 0):

To plagiarize [my answer on a Movies Meta](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4465/65663):

This changed at some point and is not in preferences; now the way to hide tags rather than just gray them out is a box on the right side of the homepage:

[image: Ignored tags are just grayed out]

If you click the `Hide questions in your ignored tags` button, they will be hidden now:

[image: They are hidden now]