# Is My Little Pony: Equestria Girls on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

MLP:FIM has been discussed before and I think the consensus is that it's on-topic.

I've watched a lot of MLP (FIM and the generations before), and now my daughter has exposed me to the latest abomination^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H variation: [Equestria Girls.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2908228/)  In this new show,

> Twilight Sparkle and Spike travel through a portal to "another world" where Spike is transformed into a dog and Twilight into a high-school girl.  In the course of their quest, they meet 5 other girls who are remarkably similar to the other 5 ponies.  (Who'd have guessed?!)

[This question seems to be about](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38753/did-rarity-graduate-from-school) Equestria Girls, and it's probably clear from my comments there and here that I don't see much redeeming value in the show.  Although it's a spin-off of FIM, I'm hoping it could be declared off-topic.  The focus of the show is not so much magic and talking ponies as it is "standard" high-school girl situations, which doesn't seem very SF&F to me.

Please, can it be deemed off-topic?

Comment: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1979/1027

Answer (score 8):

### The *Equestria Girls* film is just as topical as the *Friendship is Magic* show.

The film ([*Equestria Girls* is a film](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Little_Pony:_Equestria_Girls) which got limited theatrical release, not a spin-off show; it's in continuity with the series) is actually very much about magic and talking ponies; the "high-school girl situations" B-plots only exist to serve the overarching A-plot story of a stolen magic item hidden in an alternate universe similar to our own.

Since your reason for thinking it's not SF&F is inaccurate and your primary motive for wanting the film declared off-topic is that you don't like it, I can't give any weight to the request. Declaring *Equestria Girls* as non-fantasy is akin to declaring that [the episode where Teal'c hallucinates he's a firefighter](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/The_Changeling) isn't science fiction.

If you don't like the pony questions, [you can make it so you never see them again](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1979/13941) without imposing your dislike on the rest of the site.